# HREF Links Not Working When Using JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="example">
              <h3 id="example2"><a href="##############">NEWS</a></h3>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

For some reason links will not work when I use a jQuery plugin (ArcText.js). The script individually rotates letters to a certain angle based on how many letters, width, height, etc. I never thought it would affect links, any ideas?

Comment: It's not quite a dumb question and he apparently is new to the community. It will be good if you guys explain why is he getting a downvote so he can learn from there.

Answer (score 0):

ArcText splits string into individual characters, therefore breaking the anchor.

http://jsfiddle.net/6HRWK/

What you need to do is to move the anchor outside

```
<div class="example">
            <a href='#####'>
              <h3 id="example3">news news news news </h3>
            </a>
    </div>
```

and it will work.

Comment: That worked great, thank you so much. Sorry for the apparently dumb question. (-3 rating)